# not able to capture '?' in get request in tornado python

Tags: python, tornado

Below is my code

```
import tornado.httpserver 
import tornado.ioloop 
import tornado.web


class handle_request(tornado.web.RequestHandler):   
    def get(self,path):
       self.write(path+"..............///")        

app = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[(r"/(.*)", handle_request)])
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
http_server.listen(9999) 
print("http://127.0.0.1:9999")
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

when i got to url http://127.0.0.1/jo it is printing `jo..............//` which is correct but when i replace `jo` with `jo?g` it is still printing the same `jo...............//` which i dont want. So how to capture '?' from the url.
I noticed that if i pass `jo%3Fg` then it is printing `jo?g.........//` but how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The url structure follows ([URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator)):

```
 scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]
```

The `sda=qwe` is a query (or querystring) and it is not part of the path, `?` is only delimiter. To capture `query` use `request.query`

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


class handle_request(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self,path):
        self.write(
            "{}{}..............///".format(
                path, self.request.query)
        )
        # or whole uri part
        self.write(
            "{}.............///".format(self.request.uri)
        )

app = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[(r"/(.*)", handle_request)])
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
http_server.listen(9999)
print("http://127.0.0.1:9999")
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

To get params separately (parsed query) use request's method [get_argument](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_argument).

Comment: query is capturing everything after "?" but not able to capture "?" itself. Thanks! btw.

Comment: I've edited answer. `self.request.uri` stores stores path and querystring with `?` :)